# How do you match against an OR case in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

The Playwright documentation says "Comma-separated list of CSS selectors will match all elements that can be selected by one of the selectors in that list." but it doesn't work.

If I do this:

```
await expect(page.locator('text="Banana"')).toBeVisible();
```

it matches, but if I do this:

```
await expect(page.locator('text="Banana", text="foo"')).toBeVisible();
```

it hangs

Is this not a "CSS selector"? how do I do the equivalent properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is not a CSS selector. However, you can do it this way:

```js
await expect(page.locator('span:has-text("Banana"), span:has-text("foo")')).toBeVisible();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Now (From v1.33) you may use [OR](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-or) condition natively in Playwright

```
await expect(locatorA.or(locatorB)).toBeVisible()
```

**Simple Example:**

Consider a scenario where you'd like to click on a "New email" button, but sometimes a security settings dialog shows up instead. In this case, you can wait for either a "New email" button, or a dialog and act accordingly.

```
const newEmail = page.getByRole('button', { name: 'New' });
const dialog = page.getByText('Confirm security settings');
await expect(newEmail.or(dialog)).toBeVisible();
if (await dialog.isVisible())
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Dismiss' }).click();
await newEmail.click();
```